# Power Bi measure returning incorrect values when referencing row of a matrix visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

[A working file can be found here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FzUK2SkOwVkmVhzfbRP-quE9kNmNvWpn/view?usp=drive_link)

In this simple example, there are two tables: Scope and State:

| Scope | Index |
| --- | --- |
| National | 0 |
| State | 1 |
| NY | 2 |
| CA | 3 |

| State | Index | Scope |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NY | 2 | State |
| CA | 3 | State |

there is a relationship established on the Scope column. I have a slicer for Scope[Scope].

I want a measure that will, in a matrix visual, tell me whether the selected scope matches the name of the state:

[image]

```
StateisSelectedScope = 
IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Scope'[Scope]) = SELECTEDVALUE(State[State]), 1, 0)
```

AS you can see the problem is that all values are  0 despite the fact that I have selected NY in Scope.

The expected result ought to be:

| State | StateisSelectedScope |
| --- | --- |
| NY | 1 |
| CA | 0 |

What is it that I'm missing in my formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you have a relationship between the two based on `[Scope]` columns.

Try this one which will work for `State` or for individual states selected in the `Scope` slicer (note `REMOVEFILTERS` to remove the slicer relationship context):

```
Selected = 
  var scopes = DISTINCT('Scope'[Scope])
  var r = COUNTROWS('State')
  var s = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(FILTER('State', 'State'[State] IN scopes)),
    REMOVEFILTERS('Scope')
  )
  return COALESCE(r, s, 0)
```